# We can’t mix the objects (or libraries) compiled by g++ and clang++ ? at least on Mac?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, clang++

a function as

```
MyFunction(std::string)
```

is compiled with g++ on Mac as :

```
__Z6MyFuncSs
```

demangled as :

```
MyFunction(std::string)
```

while compiled with clang++, it is:

```
__Z6MyFuncNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

demangled as:

```
MyFunc(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)
```

don’t have the same problem on Linux
Anybody know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compilers are compatible, but their default standard libraries are not.

> don’t have the same problem on Linux Anybody know why ?

On GNU/Linux you are probably using clang + libstdc++, so it is compatible with GCC + libstdc++, because it uses the same definition of `std::string` from libstdc++.

On Mac OS X you are using clang + libc++, which is not compatible with GCC + libstdc++, they define `std::string` differently so you get different mangled names.

One option is to use `-stdlib=libstdc++` when compiling with Clang on Mac OS X, to tell it to use libstdc++, however the version of libstdc++ included with Mac OS X is ancient and doesn't support any of C++11. Doing that might also mean you can't link to other native Mac OS X libraries that use the C++ standard library, because they would probably not have been built with `-stdlib=libstdc++`

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard requires there to be a way to disambiguate overloaded names, but it leaves the actual method for doing so up to the implementation. Most implementations use name mangling to achieve this, but do it their own unique way.

The bottom line is: Don't expect any two compilers to use the same name mangling technique. Even two versions of the same compiler can change (and have changed) how they perform name mangling.

Comment: GCC and Clang both conform to the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) on GNU/Linux and Max OS X so they use the same mangling.